# If $f(a,b)=f(a,c)f(c,b)$ for all $a,b,c$, when can we conclude $f(a,b)=g(a)/g(b)$ for some $g$?

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

Suppose an unknown function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies

$$f(a,b)=f(a,c)f(c,b),$$

for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Under what conditions can we rigorously conclude that $f$ must be some quotient

$$f(a,b)=\frac{g(a)}{g(b)},$$

for an unknown function $g$? What assumptions do we have to make about $f$, does it need to be analytic, or just continuous?

A physics text I am reading states this as obvious, but I am wondering if there is a way to prove it rigorously.

Comment: If you know that $f(a,b)\ne 0$ for all $a,b$, then define $g(x) := f(x,1)$.  Then for any $a,b$, $f(a,1)=f(a,b) f(b,1)$ so $f(a,b)=\frac{f(a,1)}{f(b,1)}=\frac{g(a)}{g(b)}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Exactly, In fact it is sufficient that there exist a $b_0$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb R, f(x,b_0)\neq0$. I am still thinking about the case when we cannot find such a $b_0$.

Comment: If $f(a_0,b_0)=0$ for some $a_0,b_0$, then $f(a,b_0) = f(a,a_0) f(a_0,b_0)$ for all $a$.  Thus, $f(a,b) = f(a,b_0) f(b_0,b) = 0$ for all $a,b$; therefore, $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(a,a)=f(a,a)f(a,a)$ so $f(a,a)\in\{0,1\}$

If there exists $a_0$ such that $f(a_0,a_0)=0$ then $$f(x,y)=f(x,a_0)\underbrace{f(a_0,y)}_{\text{develop this}}=f(x,a_0)f(a_0,a_0)f(a_0,y)=0$$ and $f=0$ everywhere, this is not interesting.

So let assume $f(a,a)=1$ for all $a$.

From this we get that $f$ does not annulate since $f(a,a)=f(a,b)f(b,a)=1$

And we get $f(a,b)=\dfrac 1{f(b,a)}$.

So choose for instance $g(x)=f(x,0)$ then $f(a,0)=f(a,b)f(b,0)\iff f(a,b)=\dfrac{g(a)}{g(b)}$

*Note: there could be the case $f(a,b)=0$ and $f(b,a)=\infty$, so assuming $f$ defined everywhere seems a sufficient condition.*

Comment: You seem to assume that $f(a,a)=0$ for all a or $f(a,a)=1$ for all a. In your second sentence $f(a,a)=0$ only says $f(a,b)=0$ for all b, but the first coordinate is fixed. How can you say that this case is not interesting?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In fact $f(x,y)=f(x,a)f(a,y)=f(x,a)f(a,a)f(a,y)=0$ so if one $f(a,a)=0$ then $f=0$ everywhere. It is better redacted like this.

Comment: thanks for the explanation